# Boost::ptree - Accessing a property tree node contained in a list

Tags: c++, json, parsing, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm trying go get data from some weather API which returns a JSON.
I read that every item in a list is considered as a node without "label", but, here, inside the list are contained two nodes. How do I access to the `description` label, since `root.get<string>("weather.description")` throws a `Node does not exist` error ?

**What I tried** (Which returned nothing):

```
for (auto it: root.get_child("weather")) {
    cout << it.first.data() << "+";
    cout << it.second.data() << endl;
}
```

**weather.json**:

```
{
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": "701",
            "main": "Mist",
            "description": "brume",
            "icon": "50n"
        },
        {
            "id": "502",
            "main": "Sun",
            "description": "soleil",
            "icon": "50b"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for this! I thought weather was a list of 8 separate nodes, but it's actually two children of weather. This way, I can access to their individual data with the following:

```
for (auto it: root.get_child("weather")) {
    cout << it.second.get_child("description").data() << endl;
}
```

Which returns:

```
brume
soleil
```